# ReactJS passing custom components to a grid

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm creating a grid(data table) component. It works like that:

```
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefinitions: [
        {title: 'Test1', component: <ExampleColumnComponent />},
        {title: 'Test2', component: <Example2ColumnComponent />},
    ]
}

<Grid options = {gridOptions} />
```

Inside Grid component:

```
records.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.id}>
    {
        props.options.columnDefinitions.map((column, index) => {
        return (
            <TableCell key={index} >
                {column.component}
            </TableCell>);
        })
    </TableRow>))
```

Inside Grid component i have map which renders components and it work if I don't pass any props to the child components.

```
export const ExampleColumnComponent = () =>{
    return (<div>TEST lalalalala</div>);
}
```

But when I use props here it doesn't work:

```
export const ExampleColumnComponent = (props) =>{
    return (<div>{props.row}</div>);
}
```

I got a lot of react errors on the runtime such as:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
> built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
> but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX
> literal instead of a component
>
> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

I don't know how to pass this row object to the child component inside Grid component and make this work?

Comment: "But when I use props here it doesn't work" What doesn't work? What happens? What should happen? What is happening that shouldn't? Is there any error? What is the error? Please clarify your definition of what should and shouldn't work

Comment: @Vencovsky you are right. I added errors messages which I get on the runtime. And also I have not idea how to pass row object to the component instead of rendering it like that: {column.component}

Comment: Another ambiguous part of your question is: What should `props` inside `ExampleColumnComponent` should be? And where you should pass it from? Is the `Grid` component that will pass the props? Or you will pass it in `gridOptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use createElement, for example:

```js
import {createElement} from 'react'

//...

records.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.id}>
    {
        props.options.columnDefinitions.map((column, index) => {
        return (
            <TableCell key={index} >
                {createElement(column.component, props)}
            </TableCell>);
        })
    </TableRow>))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I got many react errors, like this: "react.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <ColumnDefinition />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?"

Comment: Yeah, my bad, didnt explain, you need to pass the function name, for example: createElement('ColumnDefinition ', props)